# Black borders in Andengine

Tags: andengine

I am using Andengine and when I start the examples there are black borders on left and right of the screen. Like this:

```
10000001
10000001
10000001
```

where 1 is black and 0 is not black. On my phone (Google Nexus 4) it is always. In emulator sometimes. it is in all examples from here: https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngineExamples

What is causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely this is because of the ResolutionPolicy you defined. For example if you choose the RatioResolutionPolicy AndEngine will try to keep the same width/height ratio, even if the real device resolutions vary. If you have a screen that is wider than the ratio allows, it will show the mentioned black bars.

You can find all the resolution policies in the GitHub [Folder](https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine/tree/c7ad23890cce706643f244734f1f7899dac49246/src/org/andengine/engine/options/resolutionpolicy)

Consider using [CroppedResolutionPolicy](http://www.andengine.org/forums/gles2/targeting-multiple-display-resolutions-t6794.html) that stretches the image beyond the borders and instead of black bars, you will get a bit of your screen cropped. The linked class will also give you two methods to find out how much was cropped.